# VPC activating message

Tags: amazon-web-services

I got a mail from AWS that shows that I am activated a new VPC security group. But I removed all instances and VPC from my account. The mail shows like below:

Dear Amazon EC2 Customer,

Thank you for activating the Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) service for your Amazon Web Services account. Here are a few useful resources to help you familiarize yourself with VPC:

May I know the reason for this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Eleena Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon my experience, when you first use an AWS resource, Amazon sends you an introductory email with links to learn more about that service.

This does not mean that you are currently using the service. IMHO this is just an educational email to a) provide you with links to learn more b) to remind you that you are using a service in case you forget c) promote AWS.